# Initialize a SequenceList by using a second rank pointer

Tags: c, list, function, pointers, memory-management

I want to initial the sequence list by using a second rank pointer,which point to the STRUCT I made for the sequence list. I tried ,  the script can be compiled to an executable file ,but fail to operate.

I am using C with the DEV CPP 5.11 as the IDE.

I just want to use the *Sqlist as my parameter to initialize a sequence list...

here is the sequence list .

```
/* can be compiled ,but fail to execute.*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define LISTSIZE 10
typedef int ElemType;
typedef struct List{
    ElemType *elem;
    int length;
    int listsize;  
}List,*Sqlist;

int InitList(Sqlist *L){   
    (*L)->elem=(ElemType*)malloc(sizeof(ElemType)*LISTSIZE);
    if (!(*L)->elem)  return -1;
    (*L)->length=0;
    (*L)->listsize=LISTSIZE;
}
int main(){
    Sqlist La;
    InitList(&La);
}
```

And this is comfusing compared with the linklist I made with a second rank pointer as the paramenter of the Initialize function.

```
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <typeinfo.h>
typedef int ElemType ;
typedef struct LNode{
    ElemType data;
    struct LNode* next; 
}LNode,*LinkList; 

int InitList(LinkList *L) {
    (*L)=(LinkList)malloc(sizeof(struct LNode));
    if (!*L) return -1;
    (*L)->data= 0;
    (*L)->next =NULL;
    printf("successfully initialized.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Don't you see the difference? In the linked list, you allocate space for the node itself and then fill it. In you sequence list, you allocate to `(*L)->elem`, although `*L` doesn't exist yet.

Comment: (I find the practice of allocating a dummy node for an empty list questionable, too. A linked list is a list that has no nodes and it can be initialised when it is defined: `List *La = NULL;`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice how the second code does allocate dynamically space for the list, before accessing its members:

```
(*L)=(LinkList)malloc(sizeof(struct LNode));
(*L)->data= 0;
```

Now you go and do:

```
Sqlist La;
InitList(&La);
```

which will execute this:

```
int InitList(Sqlist *L) {   
    (*L)->elem=(ElemType*)malloc(sizeof(ElemType)*LISTSIZE);
```

But there is no memory for the pointer! Where does it point? Nobody knows for sure. You dereference the pointer, ask for its member `elem`, and boom! You just invoked *Undefined Behavior*, for sure!

> the code compiles but fails to operate.

That's way your program "won't operate", since you have a logical error, as mentioned above.

You first need to allocate memory for `Sqlist`, as you did for `LinkList` before, and then access its members.

---

PS: It's good practice to initialize pointers to NULL, like this: `Sqlist La = NULL;`.

Oh and by the way, unrelated to your problem, [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) No!

Comment: thank you for your help:D,  I realise that I did not allocate a space for the L itself,so I add " (*L) =(Sqlist)malloc(sizeof(Sqlist));  " before in the Initial function of my Sequence list , and it works!    PS:this is my first question in stack overflow ,I am so exciting when someone did notice my question and answer it !Thanks again for your help！

Comment: Great @justinRen! Well here when an answer helps, we *accept* it, with the tick mark on the left of my answer.